# Macbook Trackpad Tap To Drag Issues

Tags: trackpad, multi-touch, magic-trackpad

I'm having a weird problem that just started with my 2012 15" Retina Macbook Pro with Yosemite. The ability to tap and drag using the internal trackpad has stopped working. All the other gestures work just fine, including three finger drag (when I enable it - it's off by default) and two finger scrolling.

I can perform the gesture just fine using a wireless Magic Trackpad.

I've tried both SMC and PRAM resets and nothing helps. Anyone seen the same issue?

Comment: Do You have any additional app installed like Better Touch Tool?

Comment: No, no additional apps installed.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like apple moved the option for enabling tap-to-drag to the accessibility pane. You can enable it there:

[image: Select Mouse & Trackpad in the accessibility pane of the system preferences and enter the Trackpad Options]
[image: Enable dragging]

*Note:* ticking three-finger drag (in the Trackpad prefs pane) will change the Accessibility-pane setting. Unticking the drag setting in the Trackpad-pane first then follow these instructions to check your Accessibility preferences.

Comment: Thanks, I've enabled that, and it still doesn't work. As I stated, tap to drag works for external magic trackpads, but not for the internal ones with this set.

Comment: Note that ticking three-finger drag (in the Trackpad prefs pane) will change the Accessibility-pane setting. Unticking the drag setting in the Trackpad-pane first then following these instructions, is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have "Enable dragging" under Acessibility turned off and "Tap to click" turned on under Trackpad -> Point & Click. Everything both clicking (by tapping) and dragging works on my internal trackpad.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is still relevant (I will update if needed or stops working). 
Just confirmed it on a new 2016 MacBook: both three finger drag + tap and drag works.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/215339/72142

Answer (score 0):

I had just done some testing to check this out when answering [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180620/enabling-both-trackpad-drag-lock-and-3-finger-drag-at-once/180657#180657) before I found my way here. That ability, at least on the Bluetooth Multitouch Trackpad, seems to be gone, at least for now. See the other answer if you want a few more minor details.